# Cube's awkward shape when rendered on a small screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm stacking a series of small divs to show a series of statistics. The problem is to display them correctly on a mobile phone. Can you suggest an alternative for me? It's worth noticing that this design came from an admin template.

This is what you'd see on a bigger screen:

[image: Cubes1]

And the following is the way the cubes are displayed while using a cellphone:

[image: Cubes2]

```
<div class="col-2">
            <div class="bg-success p-10 text-white text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-warehouse m-b-5 font-16"></i>
                <h5 class="m-b-0 m-t-5">414</h5>
                <small class="font-light">Bodega stock</small>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I've read about responsive typography but I'm not sure how should I proceed.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you have tried and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

From a designer point of view, I think what you should do is making the bottom columns be rows instead, so, in mobile, they would all be the same width as the blue box.

This should be pretty easy using Bootstrap 4, your col div would be:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4> ... </div>
```

Something like that.

Comment: Do you think it could look the same way as they do now on a big screen and look better on a mobile phone if I create two rows (one for each blue cube)? I'll have to try it out later though.

Comment: @ffuentes I think that now you have two rows, the first one having two columns, the second having 6; What I suggest is on mobile phones having only two columns per row.

Comment: The thing is each blue cube is related to its 3 lower cubes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two options :

- Display the 'total disponible' and 'total reversa' side by side on big screen, but one under each other on responsive, which can be easily done using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- Like a fellow said above, display the green, black and yellow divs in column, with width set to 100%